# Lognormal Random Numbers Centered around a high value

Tags: numpy, random, scipy

I am trying to create random numbers from a lognormal distribution using numpy/scipy.

The mean is given as 2000 and sigma as 800.

If I create my random valus using numpy.random.lognormal(mean=2000, sigma=800, size=10000)
all I get is very high or inf numbers.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful: the `mean` and `sigma` arguments correspond to the distribution of the log of the `lognormal` distribution; the actual arithmetic mean of the distribution is `exp(mean + sigma**2/2)`, which evaluates to `inf` in standard double precision floating point when `mean=2000` and `sigma=800`.

See 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html#numpy.random.lognormal
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
for more details.

Comment: is there an easy way to transform my mean and sigma to the needed values?

Comment: the logmean of the distribution is known, but I need the mean of the underlying normal distribution.

Comment: The wikipedia article has the conversions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments).  See also: www.stanford.edu/~bkravitz/research/lognormal.pdf (equations (3) - (6) give the conversions).

Comment: @LukasMosser use `numpy.random.lognormal(mean=np.log(2000),sigma=np.log(800),size=10000)`...or maybe it's `np.log10`. Can't remember the math

Comment: @Paul H: No, it is not that simple.  Read the link that I gave for the formulas.

Comment: Maybe there should be a function that does this for us?  :|