# A lognormal distribution in python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I have seen several questions in stackoverflow regarding how to fit a `log-normal distribution`. Still there are two clarifications that I need known.

I have a sample data, the logarithm of which follows a normal distribution. So I can fit the data using `scipy.stats.lognorm.fit` (i.e a `log-normal distribution`)

The fit is working fine, and also gives me the standard deviation. Here is my piece of code with the results.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

sample = np.log10(data) #taking the log10 of the data

scatter,loc,mean = stats.lognorm.fit(sample) #Gives the paramters of the fit 

x_fit = np.linspace(13.0,15.0,100)
pdf_fitted = stats.lognorm.pdf(x_fit,scatter,loc,mean) #Gives the PDF

print "scatter for data is %s" %scatter
print "mean of data is %s" %mean
```

[image]
**THE RESULT**

```
scatter for data is 0.186415047243
mean for data is 1.15731050926
```

**`From the image you can clearly see that the mean is around 14.2, but what I get is 1.15??!!`** Why is this so? **`clearly the log(mean) is also not near 14.2!!`**

**In [THIS POST](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/%7Ejsteven5/blog/lognormal_distributions.ipynb) and in [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534562/scipy-lognormal-fitting) it is mentioned that the `log(mean)` is the actual mean.**

But you can see from my above code, the fit that I have obtained is using a the **`sample = log(data)`** and it also seems to fit well. However when I tried

```
sample = data
pdf_fitted = stats.lognorm.pdf(x_fit,scatter,loc,np.log10(mean))
```

The fit does not seem to work.

**1) Why is the mean not 14.2?**

**2) How to draw fill/draw vertical lines showing the 1 sigma confidence region?**

Comment: Please post a subset of the data or fake data that replicates the problem so we can test out your sample code.

Comment: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/460413/test.txt this is a text file with the data

Comment: The mean you show is log(mean), 10.**1.15731=14.36

Comment: @CTZhu thanks for the info! But I tried for another sample, for which the mean is 14.1 but I get `1.07` for which `10**1.07` is `11.24`

Comment: You might get more traction for this question on stats.stackexchange.com. You'll find more people there who can answer questions like this one.

Comment: You shouldn't do `sample = np.log10(data)` (unless you are trying to fit some sort of log-log-normal distribution).  Just give `data` to the `stats.lognormal.fit()` method.  Also, you'll probably want to use the argument `floc=0` in the call to `fit()`.  The `loc` parameter of the distributions in `scipy.stats` is a pure translation;  it is not normally used with a log-normal distribution.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser When I follow your advice, I get a much larger stddev. I would like to show the graph in log10(data) and perform the fit. Is that not possible with `lognorm.fit`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say

> I have a sample data, the logarithm of which follows a normal distribution.

Suppose `data` is the array containing the samples.  To fit this data to
a log-normal distribution using `scipy.stats.lognorm`, use:

```
s, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(data, floc=0)
```

Now suppose mu and sigma are the mean and standard deviation of the
underlying normal distribution.  To get the estimate of those values
from this fit, use:

```
estimated_mu = np.log(scale)
estimated_sigma = s
```

(These are *not* the estimates of the mean and standard deviation of
the samples in `data`.  See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for the formulas
for the mean and variance of a log-normal distribution in terms of mu and sigma.)

To combine the histogram and the PDF, you can use, for example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

plt.hist(data, bins=50, normed=True, color='c', alpha=0.75)
xmin = data.min()
xmax = data.max()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
pdf = stats.lognorm.pdf(x, s, scale=scale)
plt.plot(x, pdf, 'k')
```

If you want to see the log of the data, you could do something like
the following.  Note the the PDF of the *normal* distribution is used
here.

```
logdata = np.log(data)
plt.hist(logdata, bins=40, normed=True, color='c', alpha=0.75)
xmin = logdata.min()
xmax = logdata.max()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=estimated_mu, scale=estimated_sigma)
plt.plot(x, pdf, 'k')
```

---

By the way, an alternative to fitting with `stats.lognorm` is to fit `log(data)`
using `stats.norm.fit`:

```
logdata = np.log(data)
estimated_mu, estimated_sigma = stats.norm.fit(logdata)
```

---

Related questions:

- [Fitting lognormal distribution using Scipy vs Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630647/fitting-lognormal-distribution-using-scipy-vs-matlab)
- [Lognormal Random Numbers Centered around a high value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937824/lognormal-random-numbers-centered-around-a-high-value)

Comment: Now that's a cheeky way to go about! I never thought of using the `norm.fit` and using the `log(data)`, works perfectly!