# Seaborn distplot: fit distribution with some fixed parameres

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-fitting

I want to fit some distribution, say gamma, to a given data array `x`, and plot the corresponding density function. I can make this easily via `seaborn.distplot` and `scipy.stats`:

```
sns.distplot(x, fit = stats.gamma)
```

However, let's say that I want some parameters of this distribution to remain fixed, for example `loc`. When I'm using `fit` function from `scipy.stats` with fixed `loc`, I write it as

```
stats.gamma.fit(x, floc = 0)
```

Is there a way to pass `loc=0` to `fit` in `distplot` function and achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.
To find the Gamma distribution approximation of a given data set, you can use liklihood function. This is the link for the formulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution
Here I have generated some random numbers based on a given gamma parameters. Then I have used the data and maximum liklihood to find the parameters of the distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import psi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Generating Random variable based on Gamma dist:

shape, scale = 3., 5.  # 
s = np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)

plt.hist(s, 50, density=True)


# Solving Liklihood:
Log_s=np.log(s)
Mean_s=np.mean(s)
Size_s=np.size(s)

k=fsolve(lambda k: np.log(k)-psi(k)-np.log(Mean_s)+(1/Size_s)*np.sum(Log_s),.1)
theta=Mean_s/k

sns.distplot(np.random.gamma(k, theta, 1000), hist=False, label='Gamma')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the condition that `sns.distplot(x, fit = stats.gamma)` will indeed show a reasonable plot and that `stats.gamma.fit(x, loc = 0)` would give the desired statistics, you can supply the argument via the `fit_kws`:

```
sns.distplot(x, fit = stats.gamma, fit_kws={"loc" : 0})
```

*[This answer is based on reading [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) and is untested, because no usecase was given in the question.]*

Comment: Nope. AttributeError: Unknown property floc

Comment: As the answer said, "under the condition...". Now it seems there is an error in the question. It should read `loc` instead of `floc`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to not plot the fit using distplot, but using the approach described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989712/plotting-fit-of-lognormal-distribution-after-fit-by-scipy-using-seaborn). Simple example provided:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.gamma(2, scale=2, size=5000),
                  columns=['samples'])

params = stats.gamma.fit(df.samples, loc=0)
xvals = np.linspace(0, df.samples.max())
pdf = lambda x: stats.gamma.pdf(xvals, *params)
yvals = pdf(xvals)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

df.samples.hist(bins=20, ax=ax1, normed=True, label='Samples',
                grid=False, edgecolor='k')

plt.plot(xvals, yvals, axes=ax1, c='r', label='Fit')
ax1.legend()
```

This will result in something like...
[not enough rep to embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpz1P.png)