# Translating Log Normal and Log Normal Truncated Simulations in @Risk to Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have been given a task of translating the simulations inside of the Excel plug-in @Risk to Python.  The functionalities closely line up with numpy's random number simulation given a distribution type and mu, sigma, or high and low values.  An example for what I am doing is [here](http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=46).

In the linked example, mu=2 and sigma=1.  Using numpy I get the same distribution as @Risk.

```
dist = np.random.lognormal(2, 1, 1000)
```

However, when I use numpy with the following parameters - I can no longer replicate the @Risk distributions.

mu=0.4, sigma=0.16 in @Risk:
[Histogram for 1000 rsamples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9h5X.png)

and in Python:
[histogram for 1000 rsamples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPFWj.png)

The result is two completely different distributions for the same mu and sigma.  So I am very confused now on what numpy is expecting for mu and sigma inputs.  I've read through the docs linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937824/lognormal-random-numbers-centered-around-a-high-value), but why would one set of parameters give me the matching distributions, and another set of values will not.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry - please ignore the log normal truncated portion of the question. #facepalm

Comment: One of your links explains that @RISK has two relevant functions, `RiskLognorm` and `RiskLognorm2`.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using RiskLognorm

Comment: for a more practical example: in @risk, I use the formula Lognorm(0.40,0.16) (mu and sigma) and sample 1000 times.  This results in a min=0.11,Max=1.49.  Using python np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000) I get min=0.90, max=2.38 and mean=1.51.  What?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another look at the @RISK documentation that you linked to and the docstring for [`numpy.random.lognormal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html).  The @RISK function whose parameters match those of `numpy.random.lognormal` is RiskLognorm2.  The parameters for `numpy.random.lognormal` and `RiskLognorm2` are the mean and standard deviation of the *underlying normal distribution*.  In other words, they describe the distribution of the logarithm of the data.

The @RISK documentation explains that the parameters for `RiskLognorm` are the mean and standard distribution of the log-normal distribution itself.  It gives the formulas for translating between the two methods of parametrizing the distribution.

If you are sure that the parameters in the @RISK code are correct, then you will have to translate those parameters to the form used by `numpy.random.lognormal`.  Given the values `mean` and `stddev` as the parameters used by `RiskLognorm`, you can get the parameters `mu` and `sigma` of `numpy.random.lognormal` as follows:

```
sigma_squared = np.log((stddev/mean)**2 + 1)
mu = np.log(mean) - 0.5*sigma_squared
sigma = np.sqrt(sigma_squared)
```

For example, suppose the mean and std. dev. of the distribution are

```
In [31]: mean = 0.40

In [32]: stddev = 0.16
```

Compute `mu` and `sigma`:

```
In [33]: sigma_squared = np.log((stddev/mean)**2 + 1)

In [34]: mu = np.log(mean) - 0.5*sigma_squared

In [35]: sigma = np.sqrt(sigma_squared)
```

Generate a sample using `numpy.random.logormal`, and check its statistics:

```
In [36]: sample = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, size=1000)

In [37]: np.mean(sample)
Out[37]: 0.3936244646485409

In [38]: np.std(sample)
Out[38]: 0.16280712706987954

In [39]: np.min(sample), np.max(sample)
Out[39]: (0.1311593293919604, 1.7218021130668375)
```